# Playing Sound Class Methods in Non-Activity Classes (context not working) Android

Tags: java, android, audio, methods, soundpool

I am trying to play my soundpool methods in several classes of my android project, however they are not activity classes and so I need to use context. Whenever I write the code and start the app it crashes everytime. I muustnt be using context properly. ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED. I will post code here.

```
public class Sound1{

    static SoundPool soundPool;
    static int soundId;
    static AudioManager audioManager;
    static int[] sm;

    // private final Context mContext;
    Context context;


    public Sound1(Context context){
        this.context = context;
       // mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    int maxStreams = 4;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(maxStreams)
                    .build();
        } else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(maxStreams, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }

        sm = new int[3];
        // fill your sounds
        sm[0] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound1, 1);
        sm[1] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound1, 1);
        sm[2] = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound1, 1);

        audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    public void playSound(int sound) {

        soundPool.play(sm[sound], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    }
}



Sound1 sound1 = new Sound1(this);


    public Player(GameScreen gameScreen, GameEventHandler mGameEventHandler) {
        // Store the centre of the screen
        //screenCentre.x = gameScreen.getGame().getScreenWidth() / 2;
        //screenCentre.y = gameScreen.getGame().getScreenHeight() / 2;
        this.mGameEventHandler = mGameEventHandler;
        //mDeck = new Deck(mGameScreen);
        Move1BoundingBox = new BoundingBox(
                mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenWidth()/2, mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenHeight()/2 + 20,
                210, 90);
        Move2BoundingBox = new BoundingBox(
                mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenWidth()/2, mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenHeight()/2 + 110,
                210, 90);
        ExpandedBoundingBox = new BoundingBox(mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenWidth()/2,
                mGameScreen.getGame().getScreenHeight()/2, 210, 150);
    }

    public void update(ElapsedTime elapsedTime) {
        // Consider any touch events occurring since the update;
        Input input = mGameScreen.getGame().getInput();
        sound1.playSound(1);
        if (input.getTouchEvents().size() != 0) {
            if (input.existsTouch(0)) {
                // Get the primary touch event
                isPlayerTouch = true;
```

**STACK TRACE**

> 04-21 14:08:08.609 18358-18358/uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage D/ViewRootImpl:
>   ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN 04-21 14:08:08.649
>   18358-18398/uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0 04-21
>   14:08:08.699 18358-18398/uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage V/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   isPlaying: 0 04-21 14:08:08.749 18358-18398/uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage
>   V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 0 04-21 14:08:08.969
>   18358-18398/uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   Thread-2376
>                                                                         Process: uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage, PID: 18358
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:889)
>                                                                             at uk.ac.qub.eeecs.game.cardDemo.Player.(Player.java:0)
>                                                                             at
>   uk.ac.qub.eeecs.game.cardDemo.CardDemoGameScreen.(CardDemoGameScreen.java:127)
>                                                                             at uk.ac.qub.eeecs.game.MenuScreen.update(MenuScreen.java:103)
>                                                                             at uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage.Game.doUpdate(Game.java:330)
>                                                                             at uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage.Game.access$200(Game.java:26)
>                                                                             at uk.ac.qub.eeecs.gage.Game$GameLoop.run(Game.java:527)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: "Whenever I write the code and start the app it crashes everytime" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" That is the message I am receiving, however whenever I take the Sound1 sound1 = new Sound1(this); and sound1.playSound(1); out it runs fine so I believe the problem lies in these 2 lines of code.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. Please also make sure that your code, referred to in that stack trace, is in your question.